# Kivymd 2.0.1 проблема с установкой

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

python kivymd 2.0.1.dev0, python 3.9. Проблема с модулями, выдает такую ошибку **sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _window_sdl2: Не найден указанный модуль.** , хотя этот модуль в интерпретаторе стоит такой модуль, помогите пожалуйста разобраться, как решит эту проблему.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]